# How does Vo2max dieting differ from normal gym more endurance-training dieting? How much intake is enough?

Tags: weightlifting, diet, strength-training, recommended-daily-intake, vo2max

This is my second week of vo2max training where each week has 2 rest days. I train the whole body during the week. I need to eat a lot. If I am not eating enough, catabolism wakes me up. I already took 2 times more [vitamins](http://www.fitnesstukku.fi/5/fi/artiklar/only-one-60-tabletter):

> [image]
>
> where minerals are Mg, Fe, Zn, Mangane, Copper, Selen, Crome.

than usually and doubled casein for the night -- after that muscles started to feel nice again. When I feel stiffness, taking more vitamins relaxes the body: it works, I don't know why. It is almost impossible to know which is enough: I train by feeling -- as large weights as possible, long pauses and as many times as possible. I train in gym.

**Is there any guidelines how much more vitamins, nutrition etc should a healthy athletic person take during vo2max week?**

Comment: You should be careful taking double doses of vitamins. You can overdose on some of them. Overdose in the sense that they can cause detrimental effects, not overdose in the sense of drug abuse.

Comment: @Tyler I added the vitamins and minerals to the question. When I wake up to pain (muscle soreness, catabolism) during night, whey protein helps. When I wake up to stiffness (nerve stress), the minerals help. I haven't got any bad feeling after taking extra vitamins+minerals, totally opposite: when I feel muscle soreness, whey is a key and it makes me feel so perfect. When I feel nerve soreness, minerals are a key and it makes me feel so awesome! Besides that, Mg seems to be effective, dunno why.

Comment: @hhh Avoid using "feelings" as a measurement, because it's is inaccurate, stick to V02 max tests and heart rate

Comment: @Freedo - What are you regarding as a "vo2 max" test? Anything that isn't done under lab conditions with a mask is a guess at best.

Answer (score 1):

A normal multivitamin is enough. You should be more concerned with your caloric intake and your macronutrient split. Your caloric intake should be at least the number of calories you burn. (There are calculators for that on the internet.) And your macronutrient split is the percentage of calories that come from protein, carbs (sugar), and fat.

For example, if you burn 2700 calories a day (typical for an active young male) and you choose a 40% carbs, 40% protein, 20% fat split (typical split for those looking to bulk), then you would need 1080 cal from carbs, 1080 from protein, and 540 from fat.

The type of training won't change much because the underlying principle is the same: replace what nutrients you use while training so you can train again. With vo2max training, you may be burning more carbs and fats and you'll probably build less muscle, so you might take 10% away from protein and add it to carbs. In general, if the exercise is intense, then favor more carbs. If more aerobic/endurance, then increase carbs and fat about equally.

Comment: When I do Vo2Max, I need far more minerals -- so much more stress to nerves. If I don't take minerals enough, I feel muscle stiffness later. I cannot understand why you need less protein during vo2max?

Comment: May I suggest replacing "glucose" with "carbohydrates"?